# Вызов функции php из приложения .Net Core на ubuntu

Tags: php, c#, .net-core

На сервере ubuntu есть приложение .Net Core, которому необходимо проверять логин/пароль пользователя, учетная запись которого создана в php.

Пользователь входит в приложение .Net Core, вводит логин/пароль, которые были зарегистрированы на сайте (в приложении .php)
Можно ли из приложения .Net Core вызвать функцию CheckPassword() из файла php, чтобы проверить пользователя?
Как это сделать?

Comment: Не смешивайте php и с#. Вызвать не удастся, но вы можете обратиться к серверу через http, socket, и проверить данные.

Comment: Не могли бы вы описать такой запрос подробнее?
В целом запросы послать мне удалось, но как сделать запрос на подтверждение логина/пароля - не могу найти информацию

Comment: PHP код интерпретируется, а не компилируется, и, как вывод, из него нельзя сделать что-то вроде библиотеки для пере-использования другими ЯП. Вы можете запускать его через консоль, обмениваться данными через  STDIN/STDOUT, либо через более привычные HTTP или сокет вызовы, или же более экзотичные типа общей памяти (shared memory, shmop), либо через обычный файл.

Comment: Данные о пользователе где-то хранятся, скорее всего, в БД. Вот и следует получать эти данные в C# прямо из БД. PHP при этом совсем не нужен. Просто переписать функцию проверки пароля на другой язык (там, вероятно, хеширование).

Answer (score 1):

Очевидный ответ - "сделать микросервис!".

Во многих статьях/книжках по микросервисам авторизация приводится как самый первый пример микросервиса.

То есть, архитектурно: в php-приложении следует добавить страницу, которой по HTTPS (например, просто GET'ом) передают пару "логин-пароль". А она отвечает в смысле "Правильная пара" или "Неправильная пара". Фактически, эта страница состоит их вызова функции CheckPassword(), окруженного кодом который берет аргументы и засовывает их в функцию и берет ответ функции и "показывает" его пользователю.

Если Вам хочется безопасности - можно настроить так, чтобы эта страница не торчала в интернет, а отвечала только на запросы из демилитаризованной зоны.

Вот и всё. Ваш микросервис готов. Теперь из приложения (на NET Core), в котором Вам нужна проверка логина-пароля - вы по HTTPS обращаетесь к микросервису, а он говорит, праильный ли пароль или нет.

Но, не стану лукавить, в моём ответе я просто подробнее расписал смысл комментария, который уже полчаса назад оставили под Вашим вопросом.

Comment: запрос по https - еще более лучший вариант, но
обязательно ли для этого делать страницу?
Нельзя ли сразу послать запрос к REST API сайта?

Comment: > Нельзя ли сразу послать запрос к REST API сайта? - вне всякого сомнения. просто это уже "уровень, требующий немного большей подготовки" для осуществления. я буду рад, если у Вас таким образом всё получится

Comment: >просто это уже "уровень, требующий немного большей подготовки"
- разве нет адреса, куда можно отправить запрос, как обычно при работе с REST API?

Comment: > разве нет адреса, куда можно отправить запрос - если мы говорим об одном и том же, то, чтобы такой адрес появился, нужно написать код, который обслуживает такие запросы. Если моё объяснение слишком краткое - Вы можете дополнитьсвой вопрос...

Comment: я Вас понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если действие необходимо совершить разово (не должно быть постоянным решением), если настройки ОС и .NET позволяют, вы можете обратиться к системному процессу и вызвать аналогично тому, как вызывают php из консоли:

```
php script.php login1 password1
```

в script.php производится подгрузка всего функционала (подключаете необходимые файлы или просто autoload.php), который реализует CheckPassword(); и добавляете обработка входящих (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php), передавая их в CheckPassword()

Результат выводите просто с помощью echo, системный процесс выведет это как output, а этот output из .NET заберете.

Comment: Надо, чтобы работало постоянно.
Появится время - попробую написать php